# What's the Common and the NO in this diagram

Tags: thermostat

I think the browns the common wire and the black is the normally open am I correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not an electronics *design* question. It is more appropriate to DIY.

Comment: I would agree with you, pin 4 is the normally closed contact.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

From the way the switch is drawn, pin 1 is common, pin 4 is NC, and pin 3 is NO.